# How to fix margin right after image

Tags: html, css, css-float

This is a screenshot of my page:

[image]

My problem is that I want the indentation after the image to be the same as before the image - in other words, for the part outlined in red to not be there.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tp83febk/) is a JSFiddle of my code.

CSS:

```
img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

HTML (with repetition deleted):

```
<img src="http://www.kimtradings.co.uk/ekmps/shops/kimtrading/images/e-shisha-liquid-coffe-flavour-6301-p.jpg" 
    width="150px" height="150px">
We are the only network that guarantees to grow your channel from day ONE, even for small channels!
Our network will <b>help you get a minimum of 5 new subscribers per day as soon as you join us!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the following solutions:

***1.*** just add a huge `padding-bottom`

```
img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom:2000px;
}
```

to your image. This is a cheeky solution.

Updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/tp83febk/1/

***2.*** Or you can try to add a `padding-left` to your text. For this you will have to wrap the text in a div and add the following:

```
div {
    padding-left: 180px;
}
```

Updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/tp83febk/4/

However , I suggest you to stick with option 2 as option 1 is just not very compatible.

Comment: Hey Mohit Bhasi Thank's :)

Comment: The first answer will cause issues on most web pages as it’ll push down all content below. The second answer will mean the CSS needs to know the width of the image which will create all kinds of problems as he attempts to make this work on multiple platforms.

Comment: @Zaqx yup i am aware of that

Comment: And yet you thought this was a solution? It just creates more problems.

Comment: @Zaqx let the OP change his decision. He accepted my answer as it was the most suitable answer at the time of his question. Your answer is fairly new hence it is not marked as answer

Comment: I downvoted your answer because people looking to solve their problem could see it and create more issues for themselves. You shouldn't take this personally.

Answer (score 0):

u can use one container with display block, and use 2 div with float

```
<div style="display: block;">
        <div style="float: left; width: 30%;">
        <img src="http://www.test.com/1.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
        </div>
        <div style="float: left;width: 70%;">
        text text texttext text texttext text text 
        text text texttext text texttext text text
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t a “good” way to do this in CSS without using flexbox ([good overview on flexbox here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)).

Solution below:

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0 }

section {
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section > img {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

section > p {
  -ms-flex: 1 0 20em;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 20em;
  flex: 1 0 20em;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="http://www.kimtradings.co.uk/ekmps/shops/kimtrading/images/e-shisha-liquid-coffe-flavour-6301-p.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
  <p>We are the only network that guarantees to grow your channel from day ONE, even for small channels! We are the only network that guarantees to grow your channel from day ONE, even for small channels! We are the only network that guarantees to grow your channel from day ONE, even for small channels! We are the only network that guarantees to grow your channel from day ONE, even for small channels! We are the only network that guarantees to grow your channel from day ONE, even for small channels! We are the only network that guarantees to grow your channel from day ONE, even for small channels! We are the only network that guarantees to grow your channel from day ONE, even for small channels! We are the only network that guarantees to grow your channel from day ONE, even for small channels! We are the only network that guarantees to grow your channel from day ONE, even for small channels!</p>
</section>
```

Editable demo: [http://jsbin.com/foyuli/3](http://jsbin.com/foyuli/3/edit?html,css,output)

Note: for IE9 and below you will need some additional logic (I’d recommend a different layout entirely) since flexbox is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Neither your image nor your content has any wrappers. In this case, I would suggest wrapping your image in a div and wrapping your content in a div and a p tag. Like this:

```
<div>
     <image>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Insert Content here</p>
</div>
```

Using CSS, float: left the two divs and you won't have a problem. This will give you more control over positioning and will allow you to better adapt when the content needs to be changed down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your content in a div like this:

```
<img src="..." width="150px" height="150px">
<div class="content">
   We are the only network that...
</div>
```

and then use overflow hidden

```
.content {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```